# error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'finish'

Tags: python

I want to write a code that gives as many numbers as you want and when you write the word finish, it adds all the numbers and closes the program.

```
total = 0
while True : 
    num = int(input('Please enter the number you want: '))
    if num == 'finish' :
        print(total)
        break 
    else :
        total = total + num
```

Comment: You're calling `int()` on the input immediately.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 0 
while True : 
    num = input('Please enter the number you want: ')
    if num == 'finish':
        print(total)
        break 
    else: 
        total = total + int(num)
```

use int() after reading.